# Mobilefirst server side - Working with adapters without client calling

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

is there any way to execute a mobilefirst adapter without direct client call? In other words, I need to do some operations in database data in timed mode (e.g. every tot secs).

Is there any way to do something like this?

Comment: Your query is not clear. Is your requirement,to invoke adapters outside an mobile application?

Comment: Not exactly. I know how to call adapter from ouside (using the "push notification" logic), with the invoke command & http requests, but in this way I have to create an external "scheduler" with a timer. The question is: is there something "official" in mobilefirst that can do the "scheduler" function for an adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other "official" mechanism to call an adapter function other than polling, but that is specific to push notifications and not for general adapter usage: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_configuring_a_polling_event_source.html